# Change permission recursively for all directory and exclude only one directory

Tags: chmod

I would like to change the permission recursively  all files and directories but exclude some directories.

```
find . -name user -prune -o -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

But using this, its only change the directories but not recursively. The content of directories not change.

while,

```
find . -name user -prune -o -type d -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
```

This will change all directories and its contents and include the 'user'directory which i want to exclude.

So, how to change the permission recursively  all files and directories but exclude user directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This can  be accomplished with the -path parameter.

```
find . -path dir -prune -o -name user -type d -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
```

If you wish to ignore multiple directories you can do.

```
find . \( -path dir1 -o -path dir2 -o -path dir3 \) -prune -o -name user -type d -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
```

Comment: i got this error: 
`find: bad option -path`
`find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list`

Comment: Sorry I don't have access to my terminal so you'll have to wait for another answer.